# <td> table breaks the container inside when it has a very long link included

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a table shows previously created data. My issue happens when there is a lack of "space" between words, i.e. a very long link. When I have something like a long link the table breaks out of the container (this application is on laravel and uses bootstrap CSS) and the users are unable to see the button that is next to the description.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Picture example before the problem:

[image]

Picture example after the problem:

[image]

Comment: too many tags here for no code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the CSS property `overflow-wrap`:

```
td {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

It will break words where they would not ordinarily be broken to avoid overflow breaking the layout.

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)
- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/)

To clear up any confusion with `word-wrap` (quote from MDN):

> The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called word-wrap, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to overflow-wrap, with word-wrap being an alias.

Answer (score 0):

seems like something css can solve. Add this to your css for

```
td{
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use table layout fixed and give width value for each column in percentage.

```
table {
     table-layout: fixed;
}

.row1 {
     width: 20%;
}
```